# VW Golf 6 - Error ESP and won't start

Tags: starting, vw, golf

After two days that the car stayed in the garage, I tried to start it to come to the office this morning, and... Not a chance to do it.
The engine had coughed a couple of times, but it wouldn't start. Driving wheel symbol is on and what exactly happens [is shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIHtkYdwtu8). 
I have no clue on what is happening or what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video looks to me as though the battery is dead. It doesn't sound like the engine is turning over at all, but rather the starter is just clicking. If you have a battery charger, you'll need to try and get it up to full charge. If that doesn't work, you may need a new battery. As @dlu stated, a low battery would cause the wonky stuff you're seeing from the gauges/dash lights.

Comment: Battery was in fact dead

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things in the video seem odd:

- It looks like the temperature gauge is showing the engine at normal operating temperature as you're trying start – do you have a block heater?
- The tach doesn't respond.
- The ESP error.

I'm not sure what to make of the temperature gauge, unless you have a block heater, then it looks normal. But the other bits make me think that perhaps your battery is low. That's the first thing that I'd check. The cranking sounds slow, and the ESP error could be due to a low battery getting pulled down even farther by the starter.